# Passing values from a list to Select during a Dataset query

Tags: dataset, associations, filtering, map, query

Given a `Dataset`:

```
myDs = {<|"id" -> 5, "name" -> "a", "quantity" -> 8.47|>,
        <|"id" -> 1, "name" -> "b", "quantity" -> 1.22`|>,
        <|"id" -> 2, "name" -> "c", "quantity" -> 9.61|>,
        <|"id" -> 4, "name" -> "d", "quantity" -> 6.56|>,
        <|"id" -> 3, "name" -> "e", "quantity" -> 5.17`|>} // Dataset
```

I'm using `Select` as a query operator in this way:

```
myDs[Select[#["id"] == 1&], "name"][[1]] // Normal  
(* output: "b" *)
```

I now want to pass a list of values (the ids) to `Select` so that they are tested, but I can't simply map it because of the ampersand right next to where my `Map` slot would go.
My current solution is having an ad hoc function:

```
querySelect[dataset_Dataset, testKey_String, testValue_, wantedKey_String]:=
dataset[Select[#[testKey] == testValue &], wantedKey][[1]] // Normal  

querySelect[dataset_Dataset, testKey_String, testValues_List, wantedKey_String]:=
querySelect[dataset, testKey, #, wantedKey] & /@ testValues
```

Which does the work:

```
ids = myDs[All, "id"] // Normal;

querySelect[myDs, "id", ids, "name"]
(* out: {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"} *)
```

I wonder, however, if there are ways to pass the values and bypass the clash of slots without resorting to user-defined functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Function` to proceed

```
myDs[Select[Or @@ (Function[id, #id == id] /@ {5, 4, 1}) &], "name"]
```

but there are shorter ways:

```
myDs[Select[MemberQ[{5, 4, 1}, #id] &], "name"]

myDs[Cases[KeyValuePattern["id" -> (5 | 4 | 1)]], "name"]

myDs[GroupBy[#, Key["id"] -> Key["name"], First] & /* Lookup[Key /@ {5, 4, 1}]]
```

> but what if I have a list of lists that I want to pass instead? [...] I meant a list of lists of values: in this case, different combinations of the ids, so for example `{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3,2}}`?

```
{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 2}} /. Normal[
    myDs[GroupBy[#, Key["id"] -> Key["name"], First] &]
]
```

> ```
> {{"b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"c", "d", "e"}, {"e", "c"}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This may seem a little redundant, but what if I have a list of lists that I want to pass instead? I see myself struggling again with the exact same problem (probably because I don't have a full grasp of the solution that uses Function).

Comment: @MumenRaida lists of lists of what?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a list of lists of values: in this case, different combinations of the ids, so for example
    {{1, 2, 4, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3,2}}

Comment: @MumenRaida `{{1, 2, 4, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 2}} /. 
 Normal@myDs[GroupBy[#, Key["id"] -> Key["name"], First] &]` is ok?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much.